# Como mudar o placeholder do input de com type="time" ou type="date"?

Tags: html, css, aplicação-web

normalmente quando a gente cria um `input` com `type='time'` ele vai aparecer com --:-- e um reloginho no final, o que eu quero fazer é de no lugar dele ficar com --:-- ele fique com HH:MM, tbm queria saber como faz isso quando é do tipo date, que ele fica, normalmente sendo dd/mm/aaaa quero mudar par DD/MM/AAAA, gostaria q fosse utilizando apenas css

Answer (score 0):

Os campos `time` e `date` do HTML não possuem suporte ao atributo `placeholder`, por isso mesmo colocando-o não terá efeito algum no elemento quando renderizado.

O que você pode fazer para contornar esse comportamento é exibi-lo inicialmente como `text`, que suporta o atributo `placeholder`, mas quando o usuário interagir com ele alterar o tipo para o desejado.

No exemplo abaixo configurei que quando o elemento receber o foco do usuário o tipo seja alterado para o desejado, e quando o foco for perdido voltar ao tipo `text` se não possuir um valor definido.

```html
<input 
  type="text" 
  placeholder="hh:mm" 
  onfocus="this.type='time'" 
  onblur="if (!this.value) this.type='text'"
>

<input 
  type="text" 
  placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" 
  onfocus="this.type='date'" 
  onblur="if (!this.value) this.type='text'"
>
```

Perceba que dadas as configurações padrões de renderização de cada elemento, o tamanho, entre outras propriedades, pode sofrer alterações quando alteramos o tipo, mas isso você pode controlar com CSS, se for do seu interesse, de forma a melhorar a usabilidade.

Comment: não tem uma propriedade no css q age diretamente  nesses  placeholders default do time e do date q lá daria para modificar eles??